# How to git restore ${project.build.directory} before commit

Tags: git, maven, zsh

I want to remove entire "${project.build.directory}" folder from the git tracked changes before i commit. There are dozens if not like a hundred git files in that generated build folder. How can i remove it from the tracked changes?
When i try to do

```
git restore --staged ${project.build.directory}
```

I get a "zsh: bad substitution" and am unable to restore the maven folder git state. I want to restore the state before i accidentally added the build folder to my tracked folder and also add the project build directory into my .gitignore to prevent it from happening again

Comment: `project.build.directory` is not a valid shell variable name. What makes you think `${project.build.directory}` has any meaning?

Comment: the ${project.build.directory} shows up in the list of changed and tracked files/directories when doing git status and stuff

Comment: Do you mean that this is the name of a file? You have a file whose name is literally `$`, then `{`, then `p`, etc., all the way out to a final `}`? That's a rather evil file name for software to generate (probably a bug), but you just need to quote the pathname to tell zsh that the `$` is not a directive to *zsh*,  i.e., that zsh should just pass the file name on to *Git*. This is purely a shell issue: all command line interpreters have some kind of syntax, and zsh's is to use `${...}` to denote shell variables (bash and sh share this same syntax) so you must tell the shell: "not for you".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard approach is to add your build folder to `.gitignore` file.

`zsh` complains that `${project.build.directory}` is not an existing variable.

Removing of a directory from tracked changes is made by `git rm -r --cached <DIRECTORY>`.

I am not sure whether you aren't mistaking tracked and staged. Tracked means already commited and staged means added but not yet committed. For the staged stuff, you can unstage it using `git reset <PATH>`.

Comment: I do NOT want to commit the build directory. i accidentally did the git add . and added the build folder and it got hundreds of files.... not sure how to restore it before i did that command.

Comment: I tried to do the ```git rm -r --cached ${project.build.directory}``` but it is complaining zsh: bad substitution.

Comment: Where is an identifier "${project.build.directory}" coming from?

Comment: it is the local maven build directory

Comment: `zsh` does not know this variable, just give it the real directory name.